# Controlling backlight intensity in iOS

Tags: ios

Is there any official way of controlling the backlight intensity of an iOS device from within an app?

Comment: I'd be willing to bet money that Apple would reject an app that did this. It's possible that iOS 5 officially supports it, though, considering apps like Instapaper (and Apple's own iBooks) do it.

Comment: iBooks is probably using something proprietary, but if Instapaper can do it, then there must be something officially supported.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIScreen Brightness Property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7900895/uiscreen-brightness-property)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, check the [`brightness`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIScreen_Class/Reference/UIScreen.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScreen/brightness) property in the `UIScreen` class.